# Lightroom Book Module Text Pixelation

Tags: book, adobe-lightroom

I have been using Lightroom for several years and have not run into this problem until now. I used to and usually would run Lightroom Classic on my computers which were Windows machines. I really enjoyed using the book module as I liked for each year creating a book of the best photos I took during that year and then I could easily export it to a PDF and have it printed.

However, I recently purchased a MacBook Pro which runs Lightroom incredibly well. But there is a problem in the book module now which was not there on my Windows computers or even this computer a few days ago. The text which I am typing comes up looking incredibly pixelated. When I export the PDF the text looks razor sharp (how it used to look when in the book module), but while typing or looking at pages which already have type on them there are pixelated blocks around the text, I will attach a screenshot to show what I mean. I already checked that Lightroom is not opening in Low-Resolution mode and that did not fix it. The rest of the text in Lightroom looks fine (the system text or the develop settings for example) it is just the text actually in the book.

I hope someone may have found this issue before and knows a solution thank you!

[image: The pixelated text can be seen here.]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. I wonder if this has something to do with your computer system scaling the lightroom application, for example, if it has a high resolution display.  It might be better to contact Adobe directly about this, it could even be a bug.  Tech support problems are generally off-topic here because they are difficult to diagnose without access to your computer system/settings.

Comment: I’m definitely no expert (no mac, no windows pc, no adobe products), but could this be related to anti-aliasing or hinting being switched off?

Comment: @Billy Kerr, I think you may be right, as when I hopped back onto my external monitor (bigger screen but the resolution is 1920*1080) it looked fine again. So I think It might have something to do with this.